# Fix the Model Flutter / Dart

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I have a PHP backend and I use it on my localhost so everything okay but I have a problem that the image URL I get from API is a wrong path and I can't change it from server-side so  I decide to fix it on my client-side

I can display an image on my emulator with this path :

```
http://10.0.2.2:8000/storage/app/public/171/conversions/api-icon.jpg
```

and the API gives me this path

```
http://192.168.1.114/multi-restaurants/public/storage/app/public/171/conversions/api-icon.jpg
```

I fix it by making a function to change the path but it takes a lot of work like I should put this function in every place I wanna display an image!!

I'm sure there is a way to change the path directly from the model when I receive the api
here is my model

```
class Media {
  String id;
  String name;
  String url;
  String thumb;
  String icon;
  String size;

  Media();

  Media.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap)
      : id = jsonMap['id'].toString(),
        name = jsonMap['name'],
        url =  jsonMap["url"] ,
        thumb = jsonMap['thumb'],
        icon = jsonMap['icon'],
        size = jsonMap['formated_size'];
```

This function that I'm using in every class to change path Url

```
String changepath(String uuu) {
    final uri = Uri.parse(uuu);
    print("This is $uri");
    if (uri.path.contains("multi-restaurants")) {
      print("http://10.0.2.2:8000/${uri.pathSegments[2]}/${uri.pathSegments[3]}/${uri.pathSegments[4]}/${uri.pathSegments[5]}/${uri.pathSegments[6]}");
      return"http://10.0.2.2:8000/${uri.pathSegments[2]}/${uri.pathSegments[3]}/${uri.pathSegments[4]}/${uri.pathSegments[5]}/${uri.pathSegments[6]}";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your PHP script?

Comment: Im Flutter Dev. I want to solve it from Client-Side
and I can share PHP script if you told me where maybe I can find it(folders) @NishuthanS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve the Problem with Create a Helper Class and put inside it a static function and call it in every widget I wanna display (Url)

```
 static String changer(String _string1) {
    String _string2 = _string1.replaceAll(
        "http://192.168.1.114/multi-restaurants/public",
        "http://10.0.2.2:8000");
    print(_string2);
    return _string2;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the API constantly sending the URL in "http://192.168.1.114/multi-r ... " in this format, then there is a solution for it, don't know is this a smart move or anything you looking for.Just create String type Function,pass the url from json  `url = changer(jsonMap["url"]);` and use it to convert the URL to desired URL.

```
String changer(String _string1) {
  String _string2 = _string1.replaceAll("http://192.168.1.114/multi-restaurants/public", "http://10.0.2.2:8000");
  return _string2;
}
```

Comment: This solution will work, put this `changer` function in your model, and in your `fromJson` function, use it like this: `url = changer(jsonMap["url"]);`

Comment: I tried this solution before I posed the problem to you, but it did not help. 

`The instance member 'changer' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`

@HuthaifaMuayyad @xahid_rocks

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad

Comment: In class Media, change " String url ; " to this "String url = ' ' ; " , give it a try and notify about the result  :)

Comment: `The instance member 'changer' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`
 @xahid_rocks

Comment: I Solve the Problem with Create a Helper Class and put inside it a static function and call it in every widget I wanna display (Url)

 `static String changer(String _string1) {
    String _string2 = _string1.replaceAll(
        "http://192.168.1.114/multi-restaurants/public",
        "http://10.0.2.2:8000");
    print(_string2);
    return _string2;
  }`